# Web scraping with BeautifulSoup <span>

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to  print the information inside a  tag.
But I have an empty print.

There is the website: https://mubi.com/it/films/25-watts/cast?type=cast

I'm trying to print all actors name.

Here is my code:

```
import random 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://mubi.com/it/films/25-watts/cast?type=cast' #vincitori


def main():
    response = requests.get(url)
    html =  response.text  

    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    cast = soup1.find_all('span', {'class' : 'css-1marmfu e1a7pc1u9'})
    for tag in cast:
            print(tag)
        
        



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you for supporting ;)

Comment: Hi. If you look at the raw HTML downloaded from that URL, the actor names are rendered in JavaScript. You will need something like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to parse the rendered HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the page is loaded from an external URL via JavaScript (so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it). You can use the `requests` module to simulate the Ajax request:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://mubi.com/it/films/25-watts/cast?type=cast"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__").contents[0])

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

film = data["props"]["initialProps"]["pageProps"]["film"]

cast_url = "https://api.mubi.com/v3/films/{}/cast_members?sort=relevance&type=cast&page=1"
cast = requests.get(
    cast_url.format(film["id"]),
    headers={"CLIENT": "web", "Client-Country": "US"},
).json()

# print(json.dumps(cast, indent=4))

for m in cast["cast_members"]:
    print("{:<30} {:<30}".format(m["name"], m["primary_type"] or "-"))
```

Prints:

```
Daniel Hendler                 Actor                         
Jorge Temponi                  Actor                         
Alfonso Tort                   Actor                         
Valentín Rivero                -                             
Federico Veiroj                Director                      
Valeria Mendieta               -                             
Roberto Suárez                 Actor                         
Gonzalo Eyherabide             -                             
Robert Moré                    Actor                         
Ignacio Mendy                  -
```